# Is there any example problems using Dynamic Programming having O(n^4) time complexity?

Tags: time-complexity, dynamic-programming

As we know, Dynamic Programming (DP) usually can solve problems in time O(n^2) or O(n^3) where a naive approach would take exponential time. But are there any harder problems needs O(n^4) time to solve using DP?

Comment: There are even examples where DP still needs exponential time.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I am just curious about exactly O(n^4) time problems solved by DP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a matrix with integers and can only go down and right, and u need to find the maximum sum that could be obtained starting from left-top corner to right-bottom. This could be solved in O(n^2) (d[i][j] = max(d[i-1][j], d[i][j-1]). But If it vere 3-dimensional array, the complexity would be O(n^3). If it were 4-dimensional then O(n^4) etc.